# accessing Session storage across application in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a session variable as a JSON value. I have this in my `home.component.ts` and need to access this variable in multiple places.

my code:

```
.do(data => sessionStorage.setItem('homes', JSON.stringify(data)))
var session = sessionStorage.getItem('homes');
```

How to access `session` variable throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

Define a service and inject it in yout components.
Inside this, define a getter and setter of sessionStorage and manage it.

for example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {

  constructor() { }

  public setItem(data: any){
    sessionStorage.setItem('homes', JSON.stringify(data));
  }

  public getItem(){
   return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('homes'));
  }
}
```

And then in yout home.component.ts

```
constructor(private homeService: HomeService){}

ngInit(){
this.homeService.setItem(data...); //pseudocode
}
```

and, when you want to retrieve the data you will simply call homeService.getItem().

Comment: I'm new to angular2 kindly help with samples

Comment: Done, it's a bit pseudocode but that's the way I implemented that in my last project